# How to print exception and then keep sequential executing rather than jump to rescue section

Tags: ruby

I'm practicing the Ruby

I often put the wrong code in my file intentionally

e.g.`Abc.hi`

And the program will raise error then exit.

So I have to wrapped it with `begin with` block.

How could I let the `wrong code` only show the exceptions on the console,
and keep doing the following code without wrapping with `begin with` block.

Thanks

```
require 'pry'

module Test
  def hi
    p "hihi"
  end
end

def Test.hello
  p "hello"
end

class Abc
  include Test
end
abc = Abc.new
begin
  Abc.hi
rescue Exception => e
  p e
end

binding.pry
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because that is the point of exceptions - they break the flow.

If you simply want to see the stack trace at that point, use [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-caller)

```
def a
  puts caller
end
def b
  a
end
def c
  b
end
c()
#=> prog:2:in `a'
#=> prog:5:in `b'
#=> prog:8:in `c'
#=> prog:10:in `<main>'
```